# R - sum matrix rows and columns based on groupings

Tags: r, matrix, sum, row, grouping

I have a symmetric matrix and a single specific grouping that applies to both the rows and columns. I am trying to sum only those rows and columns based on this specific grouping.

For instance, I have a 4 x 4 matrix. I also have a specific grouping such as 1,1,2,2. That is, rows and columns 1 and 2 belong to group 1 whereas rows and columns 3 and 4 belong to group 2. I would like to apply the functions rowSums or rowsum staying true to the group constraints:

My matrix:

```
        [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]      0    1    0    0
[2,]      1    0    1    0
[3,]      0    1    0    3
[4,]      3    0    0    0
```

Intuitively to help with my question, the grouping 1,1,2,2 essentially means the following:

```
        [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]      0    1   NA   NA
[2,]      1    0   NA   NA
[3,]     NA   NA    0    3
[4,]     NA   NA    0    0
```

Applying rowSums to the original matrix would yield:

```
[1] 1 2 4 3
```

Also, applying rowsum, which allows the passing of a group, only applies the grouping to the rows and still sums the columns that are not part of the group:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
1       1    1    1    0
2       3    1    0    3
```

The reason that this is an issue is because I am attempting to find the minimum value in each group. Since the above includes columns that are not part of the group the result would not be correct. I could tediously loop through the groupings and apply rowSums to obtain the sums per group and then find the minimum:

```
rowSums(mat[c(1,2),c(1,2)])
[1] 1 1 <- minimum is 1
rowSums(mat[c(3,4),c(3,4)])
[1] 3 0 <- minimum is 0
```

However, I have a large matrix and this method is not practical. I'm pretty sure there's a more efficient and easy way to do this but I can't seem to find one. Ideally I'd like the output to be something like:

```
1 1 2 2 <- grouping
1 1 3 0
```

or even

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
1       1    1   Inf  Inf
2      Inf Inf    3    0
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

**Edit:**

I am adjusting my question to the following. Given my original matrix:

```
        [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]      0    1    0    0
[2,]      1    0    1    0
[3,]      0    1    0    3
[4,]      3    0    0    0
```

and a specific grouping:

```
groups<-c(1,1,2,2)
```

I can achieve the desired output by looping through the groups:

```
groups<-c(1,1,2,2)
for(i in 1:length(groups))
{
  mat[i,which(groups[i]!=groups)]<-NA
}

mat

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    1   NA   NA
[2,]    1    0   NA   NA
[3,]   NA   NA    0    3
[4,]   NA   NA    0    0
```

How can I achieve this without the use of the inefficient loop?

Comment: How did you get the `3` in `1 1 3 0` if you are taking the minimum value

Comment: I believe he wants the rowise max of mat[1:2,1:2] and mat[3:4,3:4]. The grouping c(1,1,2,2) applies on both rows and columns.

Comment: In that step I just wanted to display the row sums per group (before searching for the minimum value per group).

Comment: It is not really clear based on the ouptut.  As you mentioned the `rowSums`, I posted a solution below

Comment: @akrun You can think of it as:

[1,] 1
[2,] 1
[3,] 3
[4,] 0

Comment: How would this generalize? For example if the matrix was 16x16?

Comment: @Sotos My matrix will always be a symmetric matrix. I select a specific grouping and attempt to find the row sums while only including those columns that are in the same group as the rows.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this helps

```
sapply(split(mat, kronecker(matrix(1:4, nrow=2, byrow=TRUE), 
       matrix(1, 2, 2))), function(x) rowSums(matrix(x, ncol=2)))
#     1 2 3 4
#[1,] 1 0 1 3
#[2,] 1 1 3 0
```

Explanation

```
kronecker(matrix(1:4, nrow=2, byrow=TRUE), matrix(1, 2, 2))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    1    2    2
#[2,]    1    1    2    2
#[3,]    3    3    4    4
#[4,]    3    3    4    4
```

The `kronecker`product of two arrays returns the grouping index as showed above.  Use that to `split` the matrix

```
split(mat, kronecker(matrix(1:4, nrow=2, byrow=TRUE), 
   matrix(1, 2, 2)))
#$`1`
#[1] 0 1 1 0

#$`2`
#[1] 0 1 0 0

#$`3`
#[1] 0 3 1 0

#$`4`
#[1] 0 0 3 0
```

It returns a `list` of `vector`s

Convert the `vector` to `matrix` and get the `rowSums` by looping over the `list` with `sapply`

Comment: Thanks. Your answer got me into thinking about using sapply on my matrix. I've edited my question above to redirect the desired output. Please take a look. Thanks!